# My <form> is not sending correctly the data to my PHP routes. Or is it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I have an PHP application integrated with HTML and some JS/JQuery. I'm trying to make a delete option by using a button that sends a form to delete inputs selected with a checkbox:

```
<?php
  $this->layout('layout');
?><header class="bg-dark">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1 id="page_name"><a href="/">Product List<span>.</span></a></h1>
      <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a id="product_adder" class="nav-link" href="/add-product">Add product</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button
            form="delete_form"
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-danger"
            id="submit-button"
            >
            Mass Delete
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

<main>
  <form action="/delete" id="delete_form" method="POST" name="delete_form">
    <div class="row w-100 mx-0 justify-content-center">
      <?php foreach($productList as $product): ?>
        <div class="card mx-2 mt-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body mt">
            <input type="checkbox" name="deleteId[]" value=<?= $product['id'];?> >
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item text-center"><?= $product['sku']; ?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item text-center"><?= $product['name']; ?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item text-center"><?= $product['price']; ?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item text-center"><?= $product['attribute']; ?></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </form>
</main>

// script.js:
$(function () {
  changeRespectiveClassFields(); // code that has nothing to do with
  selectInputCheckboxValues();
});

function selectInputCheckboxValues() {
  $("#submit-button").click(function () {
    const options = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
      options.push($(this).val());
    });

    const optionsChecked = options;

    $.ajax({
      url: "/delete",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      data: { deleteId: optionsChecked },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
    });
  });
}

// rest of the code
```

But the form was not being sent, even though I correctly referenced it in `<button>` using the `form` attribute and set the action of the form as `/delete` and the path of Ajax as `/delete` too (knowing I am being redundant).

**I expect the `id`'s in `<input>` values to be sent by the form and be catched by the `$_SERVER` superglobal in PHP, selecting the input fields on my listing products page, which is the root path**:

```
# routes.php and yeah, this is my router
<?php

use App\Product\Controller\{
  ListProductController,
  ProductFormController,
  NewProductController,
  DeleteProductController,
};

return [
  'GET|/' => ListProductController::class,
  'GET|/add-product' => ProductFormController::class,
  'POST|/add-product' => NewProductController::class,
  'POST|/delete' => DeleteProductController::class,
];


# index.php
// some code
$routes = require_once __DIR__ . '/../config/routes.php';

$pathInfo = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

The problem is that when I send the form, it passes a `PATH_INFO` as "/" (the root path) and just the `REQUEST_METHOD` as "POST". To properly hit the `DeleteProductController`, it has to go to the `/delete` path. Unfortunately it is not going. **The other router paths work correctly**.

My `php -S` logs says it somehow hits the post but nothing happens and it does not change the `$_SERVER` superglobal:

```
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55858 Accepted
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55858 [302]: POST /delete
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55858 Closing
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55870 Accepted
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55870 [200]: GET /
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55870 Closing
[Thu Feb  9 13:29:17 2023] 127.0.0.1:55878 Accepted
```

How can I make the request properly and send the form data correctly?

Comment: What's in your `$_POST`? Can you check its value?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. It is returning an empty Array.